# global handler invokation

Tags: c++, function, memory, allocation

I have overloaded new function but unfortunetly never been able to execute global handler for requesting more memory access on my compiler. I also don't understand as per below code snippet if we invoke the
global handler for requesting more memory how it is gling to allocate to P.

I appreciate if anybody can through some light on this

```
void * Pool:: operator new ( size_t size ) throw( const char *)
{
    int n=0;
    while(1)
    {
        void *p = malloc (100000000L);
        if(p==0)
        {
            new_handler ghd= set_new_handler(0);//deinstall curent handler
            set_new_handler(ghd);// install global handler for more memory access
            if(ghd)
                (*ghd)();
            else 
                throw "out of memory exception";
        }
        else
        {
            return p;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you *intend* to allocate **95.37 MB** of memory per `new` request and blindly ignore the `size` parameter passed to you? Just curious.

Comment: it is for example purpose only to give you complete picture . I am not ignoring the size parameter

Answer (score 0):

To have any effect, some other part of the program must have installed a global handler previously. That handler must also have some kind of memory to release when the handler is called (perhaps some buffers or cache that can be discarded).

The default new_handler is just a null pointer, so your code is very likely to end up throwing an exception.

Also, I would have thrown a `bad_alloc` exception to be consistent with other `operator new` overloads.

Comment: That i already have done !! my question is how global handler invoketion like  (*ghd)(); going to fulfil the memory request.

Comment: There is no magic here. The global handler can possibly free some memory that has been allocated before and that can be released in a low-memory situation. If it does, the `malloc` call might work on the next round in the while loop. For example, your program might use some large tables to save computed values that are needed several times. That saves it from calculating them more than once. When running out of memory, the program might consider dropping those tables and continue to run (only more slowly, as it now has to recalculate those values when needed).

Comment: Thanks for your replay. One more thing i would like to ask you in this thread about the use of global handler.  should it be thread safe and how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two things to discuss, the first is using **new_handler**, the second is overloading **operator new**.

## set_new_handler()

When you want use a **new_handler**, you have to register it. It is typically the first thing to do after entering **main()**. The handler should also be provided by you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

void noMemory() throw()
{
  std::cout << "no memory" << std::endl;
  exit(-1);
}

int main()
{
  set_new_handler(noMemory);
  // this will probably fail and noMemory() will be called
  char *c = new char[100000000L];
  std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
}
```

When no memory can be allocated, your registered handler will be called, and you have the chance to free up some memory. When the handler returns, **operator new** will give another try to allocate the amount of memory you requested.

## operator new

The structure of the default **operator new** is something similar you presented. From the point of the **new_handler** the important part is the **while(1)** loop, since it is responsible for trying to get memory after called the **new_handler**.

There is two way out of this **while(1)** loop:

- getting a valid pointer
- throwing an exception

You have to have this in mind when you provide a **new_handler**, because if you can not do anything to free up memory you should deinstall the handler (or terminating or throwing an exception), otherwise you can stuck in an endless loop.

I guess omitting parameter size in your code is just for test purpose.

Also see **Scott Meyers' Effective C++ Item 7** for details. As operator new must return a valid pointer even with parameter size = 0, the first thing to do in your **operator new** should be overwriting size to 1 in case of the user want to allocate 0 number of bytes. This trick is simple and fairly effective.

Comment: I did this as a below code snippet :void newhandler( ) { cerr << "The new_handler is called:" << endl; set_new_handler(0); } and also called below method at start of main:set_new_handler(newhandler);